# Firestore write limit with Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that write in a large number of documents in firestore. I get the following error: "Exception from a finished function: Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded".
I read that maybe it could be cause by the 500 commit limit. How could I manage to pass this limit?

Code: https://pastebin.com/nqsGuMm6

Log: Function terminated with status: ok (in 4/5 seconds)
And then: `Exception from a finished function: Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded`

(I have thousands of documents inside "Schedine", "in corso")

Comment: Please provide a piece of code so that others can better understand the problem and check if you are actually doing too much writes