# Calling Cloud function inside other cloud function - Error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call a cloud function inside another cloud function as below:

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  var currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  
  const risultati = await firestore.collection("Risultati").doc("risultati").get();
  const ref1 = await firestore.collection("Schedine").get();
  await ref1.forEach(async doc => {
 
    let url = "https://us-central1-betty-sport.cloudfunctions.net/check"
    await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        qs: {  name : doc},
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        
    })
  });
```

called function: https://pastebin.com/qGewBi4c
Giving the following error:

> "Exception from a finished function: FetchError: request to https://us-central1-betty-sport.cloudfunctions.net/check failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established"

Comment: Can you also share the code of that other cloud function? Something might be wrong there by chance? Also you must return a response to terminate the cloud function so do add ``res.end()` (or `res.json()` in case you want to return some data back) at the end of the function.

Comment: edited with other function

Comment: What is `req.form` in the other function? You are passing `application/json` as content type header so Firebase will parse it as JSON. Try `req.body.name` instead and passing `body: JSON.stringify({name: doc})`? I am not aware of any `qs` param in `fetch`. For testing maybe try with a single request instead of multiple in a forEach,

Comment: I'll try it. But is it possibile to do what I am doing? I don't know if calling another cloud function  is legit

Comment: Depends on your use case. To me it just seems like reading some documents, parsing them and triggering notifications. If a response must be sent to user only after that all happens, then it looks good like calling a 3rd party API. If those tasks can be done asynchronously, maybe you can use something like pubsub and process it after sending response  back to user.

Comment: This is my main problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74214373/firestore-write-limit-with-cloud-function Because I had a single pubsub to update hundreds of document but I exceed the write quotas.So I'm trying to split it in different cloud function but I don't know if it will work

Comment: I noticed that the called function has no log, so I think that the problem that causes this exception is in the first function